# numeric column having a decimal but not displaying it

Tags: r, dataframe

I encounter a strange behavior that I don't understand. Here is an example:

```
plouf <- read.table(text = "id  ttt_course  generic_name
1011010001.1    1   etanercept
           1011010001.2 1   etanercept
           1011010001.3 1   etanercept
           1011010001.4 1   etanercept
           1011010001.5 1   etanercept
           1011010001.6 1   etanercept
           1011010001.7 1   etanercept
           ",header = T)
```

The id column is the one that is strange.

```
> class(plouf$id)
[1] "numeric"
```

So it is numeric, but when I display it:

```
          id ttt_course generic_name
1 1011010001          1   etanercept
2 1011010001          1   etanercept
3 1011010001          1   etanercept
4 1011010001          1   etanercept
5 1011010002          1   etanercept
6 1011010002          1   etanercept
7 1011010002          1   etanercept
```

It display rounded value of it. The levels of it are also as strange :

```
> unique(plouf$id)
[1] 1011010001 1011010001 1011010001 1011010001 1011010002 1011010002 1011010002
```

I can of course force force to print:

```
> formatC(plouf$id,format="f",digits=1)
[1] "1011010001.1" "1011010001.2" "1011010001.3" "1011010001.4" "1011010001.5" "1011010001.6" "1011010001.7"
```

What is the reason for this behavior ? How can I avoid it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation for the print method for a data frame:

```
?print.dataframe
## S3 method for class 'data.frame'
print(x, ..., digits = NULL,
      quote = FALSE, right = TRUE, row.names = TRUE)
```

When you enter `plouf`, since it's a data frame, this is the method that prints the data frame to the console, with digits = NULL.

There are three ways around it:

1. force it (as you suggested, and also as @Florian suggested)
2. define a different class of object with a different print method.
3. set your global option for digits, e.g., `options(digits = 14)`

Personally, I try to avoid setting different options, because it makes it harder to collaborate with others if you're seeing nonstandard output.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the [`digits`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/options) option to a value greater than 10:

```
> options(digits=14)
> plouf
            id ttt_course generic_name
1 1011010001.1          1   etanercept
2 1011010001.2          1   etanercept
3 1011010001.3          1   etanercept
4 1011010001.4          1   etanercept
5 1011010001.5          1   etanercept
6 1011010001.6          1   etanercept
7 1011010001.7          1   etanercept
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the `options` settings but just print that data frame with the decimal places you can use, as Dan Hall suggested, the `print` function with the right number of digits:

```
print(plouf, digits = 11)
```

Output:

```
           id ttt_course generic_name
1 1011010001.1          1   etanercept
2 1011010001.2          1   etanercept
3 1011010001.3          1   etanercept
4 1011010001.4          1   etanercept
5 1011010001.5          1   etanercept
6 1011010001.6          1   etanercept
7 1011010001.7          1   etanercept
```